# How do I add $ and % to numbers in a column with this query?

Tags: mysql

I have the following code and result set below. How do I add $ to all the values in 'Discounted Order Total' column, along with % to all the values in the 'Maximum Discount' column?

```
SELECT product_name AS "Product Name", category_name AS "Category Name", 
COUNT(*) AS "Number Purchased", ROUND(MAX(discount_percent),2) AS "Maximum Discount", 
ROUND(SUM((list_price - discount_amount)*quantity),2) AS "Discounted Order Total"
FROM products P, order_items O, categories C
WHERE P.product_id = O.product_id AND P.category_id = C.category_id
GROUP BY product_name, category_name
ORDER BY product_name
```

[Current result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OX5F.png)

[Wanted result set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksOez.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the current (and expected) result set, as text and not as a link to an image. This makes it easier to read it. You can even shorten the result set and still make your point.

Comment: Since my account is new I can't add pictures without a link, I don't know how to translate both result sets to text

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function for this,

```
concat("$", ROUND(SUM((list_price - discount_amount)*quantity),2)) AS "Discounted Order Total"
```

will add a `$` to `Discounted Order Total` value. The same can be done for `Maximum Discount`:

```
concat(ROUND(MAX(discount_percent),2), "%") AS "Maximum Discount"
```